# Secciones encimadas por DIVS

Tags: html, css, div

Todo el cuadro de Sensores esta encapsulado, este le permite posicionarse del lado derecho. Me gustaria que este al entrar la pagina este a la altura de UPS EATON y se quede estatico a partir de ese momento hasta el final de la pagina.

Espero haberme explicado

[image: la seccion de sensores al entrar a la pagina, invade la zona de ambiente]

[image: Todo el cuadro de Sensores esta encapsulado, este le permite posicionarse del lado derecho. Me gustaria que este al entrar la pagina este a la altura de UPS EATON y se quede estatico a partir de ese momento hasta el final de la pagina. Sin invadir la sección de ambiente.]

todo en la parte de abajo esta diseñado para permitir este deslizamiento de sensores y que no obstruya

Conocen algun solucion para mi problema?

les dejo un poco del html y del css de la secciones de sensores, gracias!

```css
/* Estilos para el límite de desplazamiento */
.side-limits {
    position: fixed;
    top: 165px; 
    right: 20px; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 300px; 
}

/* Estilos para el cuadro estático */
.side-static {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px; 
    right: 200px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #f00; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    /* margin-top: 80px; */
}


.side-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: left;
    flex-direction: column; 
    height: 100vh; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -250px;
    
    /* ESTE ES EL MAIN-CONTAINER 
    Estilos para el contenedor principal, si es necesario */
}

.side-tittle {
    margin: 0;
    /* Estilos para el título del cuadro, si es necesario */
}

.side-custom {
    background-color: #e0e0e0; /* Color de fondo más oscuro del contenedor */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Esquinas redondeadas */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Sombra para resaltar el contenedor */
    max-width: 1400px; /* Anchura máxima del contenedor */
    margin-top: 10px; /* Añadir un margen superior para separar del h2 */
    width: 300px;
    height: 495px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    /* ESTE ES EL CISTOM-CONTAINER
    Estilos para el contenedor personalizado, si es necesario */
}

.side-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;

    /* CONTAINER-ITEMS
    Estilos para los ítems dentro del contenedor, si es necesario */
}

.side-box {
    background-color: #d0d0d0; /* Color de fondo de los rectángulos internos */
    flex: 1;
    height: px;
    width: 290px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* Esquinas redondeadas */
    margin: 5px;
    /* 
    INNER-BOX
    Estilos para el cuadro dentro del contenedor, si es necesario */
}
```

```html
<div class="side-limits" id="side-limits">
        <div class="side-static">
            <div class="side-container">
                <h2>Sensores</h2>
                <div class="side-custom">
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Agua Piso</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Temperatura</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Humo</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-tittle">
                        <h3>Seguridad</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-items">
                        <div class="side-box">
                            <p>cargando...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

es importante mencionar que los valores de la funcion top en .side-static, al darle valor a top es el espacio total sobre el limite superior de la pagina, si este aumento SI se desplaza hacia abajo pero se oculta de manera fija y no se visualiza toda la informacion completa

Gracias!!!

Comment: si colocas un ejemplo completo te ayudo con el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu tienes una estructura como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera parte de elementos están ordenados en 5 columnas, esta parte es irrelevante para el problema, ya que lo importante viene abajo, y básicamente no afectará en nada.

Luego tienes una serie de elementos que tienen 4 columnas, que se posicionan a la izquierda y una barra lateral a la derecha.

Entonces es tan simple como dictar que lo de la izquierda tiene un ancho del 80% y la barra lateral un 20%, además esta barra flotara a la derecha (`float:right;`) y su posición será `position:sticky` que es lo que finalmente hace todo el truco.

```css
section{
  display:grid;
  gap:10px;
}

.cuatroCol{
    grid-template-columns:repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.cincoCol{
    grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.cuadro{
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.leftside{
  width:80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
aside{
  position:sticky;
  top:30px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  margin-left:10px;
}
aside > div{
  background-color:red;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Ambiente</h2>
<section class="cincoCol">
  <div class="cuadro"></div>
  <div class="cuadro"></div>
  <div class="cuadro"></div>
  <div class="cuadro"></div>
  <div class="cuadro"></div>
</section>


<div class="leftside">
  <h2>UPS EATORN</h2>
  <section class="cuatroCol">
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
  </section>
</div>

<aside>
  <h2>SENSORES</h2>
  <div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
    <div>AAAAAA</div>
  </div>
</aside>

<div class="leftside">
  <h2>OTRA COSA</h2>
  <section class="cuatroCol">
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="leftside">
  <h2>OTRA COSA</h2>
  <section class="cuatroCol">
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
    <div class="cuadro"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef!!

resolviste mi problema, saludos :)